# Why can't I load the API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm going to call the movie API using the redux in the react application.

During the process of calling the movie API using the redux-thunk,
An error occurs while calling the callAPI function on the lib/THMb path.

```
//movie_project/src/lib/THMb.js

import axios from 'axios';

const key = "xxxxxxx";
const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${key}&language=ko&page=1&region=KR`; 

export const callAPI = async () =>{
    await axios.get(`${url}`);
}
```

```
import {  handleActions } from "redux-actions";
import axios from "axios";
import * as movieAPI from '../lib/THMb';

// action types
const GET_MOVIES = 'movie/GET_MOVIES';
const GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS = 'movie/GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS';
const GET_MOVIES_FAILURE = 'movie/GET_MOVIES_FAILURE';

export const getMovies = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_MOVIES }); 
    try{
        const res = await movieAPI.callAPI(); // failed
        dispatch({
            type: GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS, // 요청 성공
            payload: res.data.results, // API 요청 결과 값
        })
    }catch(e){
        dispatch({
            type: GET_MOVIES_FAILURE, // 요청 실패
            payload: e,
            error: true
        })
        throw e;
    }
}

const initialState ={
    movieList : [],
    error: null
}

const movie = handleActions(
    {
        [GET_MOVIES]: state => ({
            ...state,
            // loading..
        }),
        [GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => ({
            ...state,
            movieList: action.payload,
        }),
        [GET_MOVIES_FAILURE]: (state, action) => ({
            ...state,
            // loading...
        })
    },
    initialState
)

export default movie;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGdiR.jpg)

---

However, no error occurs when calling url from within the getMovies function.

```
export const getMovies = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_MOVIES }); // 요청의 시작을 알림.
    try{
        //const res = await movieAPI.callAPI(); // failed
        // success
        const res = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=xxxxx&language=ko&page=1&region=KR`);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS, // 요청 성공
            payload: res.data.results, // API 요청 결과 값
        })
```

Why do errors occur in the first case???

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the first case you are not returning anything. You should try this:

```
export const callAPI = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get(`${url}`);
    return res;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

the error occurs in **callAPI** function, not in **getMovies** because in payload you are assuming **res** variable to fetch the data from it and you successfully get it in **getMovies** function but not in **callAPI**.

because you did not return anything from **callAPI** method that's why **res** variable is null and it throws the error.

just replace you **callAPI** function with the below code.

```
export const callAPI = async () =>{
 const res await axios.get(`${url}`);
 return res
}
```

hopefully, it will work just give it a try